# Are AVX512 instrinsics supported in Clang on OSX 32-bit?

Tags: macos, clang, avx512

I get millions of errors when using AVX512 intrinsics under OSX, but only when building 32-bit app, 64-bit is fine. Is it supported? I'm including it via x86intrin.h and immintrin.h. zmmintrin.h apparently isn't there at all...

Comment: Are you compiling with `-march=skylake-avx512` in both 32 and 64-bit?  You need to include the header *and* tell the compiler it's ok to emit code using those instructions.  Anyway, beyond that we need a [mcve] of the exact error messages from a small test program or function, and your build command.

Comment: I'm doing all that. I reinstalled XCode 9 and SDK 10.13 and now 64-bit compiles fine again, and 32-bit comes with 2 undefined symbols _mm512_maskz_set1_epi64 and _mm512_mask_set1_epi64. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce it with clang6.0 (mainline, not Apple's version) on Godbolt (https://godbolt.org/z/d-mnAy), but not clang7.0.

It might be a bug, but Intel lists [`_mm512_maskz_set1_epi64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,SVML,Other&expand=1276,5146,5146,5048,5048,4667&text=maskz_set1) as the intrinsic for `vpbroadcastq zmm {k}, r64`, which is obviously only available in 64-bit mode.

Of course this is silly, and `vpbroadcastq` with a memory or xmm source is still available in 32-bit mode.  Recent clang versions that support it in 32-bit mode compile this code into a non-broadcast load of a vector constant, even in 64-bit mode:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m512i foo() {
    return _mm512_maskz_set1_epi64(0xf0, 123);
}
```

But clang5.0 and older compiles it like this, in 64-bit mode, though:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
    mov     al, -16
    kmovd   k1, eax
    mov     eax, 123
    vpbroadcastq    zmm0 {k1} {z}, rax
    ret
```

And clang 5.0 -m32 gives an internal compiler error.

---

I don't have a Mac to try actual Xcode, but it's pretty clear that some clang/LLVM versions treat `_mm512_maskz_set1_epi64` and `_mm512_set1_epi64` as 64-bit-mode-only.  You might be able to define your own for 32-bit mode using the same built-ins that the headers use.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Meanwhile I got rid of all these calls actually, it was part of the vectorlib and it turns out it is probably never used in my code, so I just removed it. Other intrinsics seem fine, so everything is good now. I don't know about the clang version though, "clang --version" reports "Apple LLVM 9.1.0", which is a bit odd...

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: Apple has their own fork of clang.  The correspondence between Apple clang/llvm versions and mainline clang/llvm is unclear; Apple may incorporate some patches but not others ahead of mainline.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was expecting something like that :)